# JQuery Select.change() isn't working

Tags: jquery

I have the following drop down set up. This dropdown will filter results of a search based on the selection from the list:

```
<div class="filterGroupHeader filterGroupHeader--tight">R People</div>
                <select id="RPeopleSelect" data-bind="options: rPeopleList, optionsText: 'FullNameReverse', optionsValue: 'CarePeopleID', value: rPeople, event: { change: applyProviderFilters() }"></select>
```

This is a click event to bring up a specific piece of information. When this option is clicked, I want the function `applyPeopleFilters()` to be called.

```
$("#quickFilter").click(applyPeopleFilters);
```

This is the function for it to call. When it calls this function, I want it to filter the results based on the selection in the RPeopleSelect dropdown.

```
function applyPeopleFilters() {
        $("#RPeopleSelect").change();
    }
```

Everything works up until the above function. The code gets into the function (I know because I've used alerts to make sure its getting there) but it's not doing anything which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with `.change()`

Comment: You seem to be triggering the `change` event explicitly. You can only see the difference if there is a `change` event handler bound to the dropdown.

Comment: [This Page](https://api.jquery.com/change/) has no change handler bound to the drop down.

Comment: editted to include change event handler bound to dropdown, but still doesn't work

Comment: That is not how you bind a `change` handler to your dropdown .. Also you are calling the `applyPeopleFilters ` function which will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function you should do something like:

```
$("#quickFilter").click(function(){
    applyPeopleFilters()
});
```

Comment: the function is getting called. I've seen alerts go off from inside the function. The .change is what isn't working.